# Instagram Basic API - Long Lived Access Token

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm building a website that integrates Instagram Basic API to show my media posts. So far, I managed to authorize via 
`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=X&redirect_uri=X&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code`,

fetch a short-lived access token via `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=X&client_secret=X&grant_type=X&redirect_uri=X&code=AUTH_CODE_RECEIEVED`,

fetch a long-lived access token (as per the response I receive) via `https://graph.instagram.com/access_token?grant_type=ig_exchange_token&client_secret=X&access_token=SHORT_TOKEN_RECEIEVED`,

and lastly, show my media posts via `https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption,media_type,media_url&access_token=LONG_TOKEN_RECEIEVED`.

However, the problem I am currently facing is that the obtained long-lived access token - **which is meant to be valid for 60 days?** - is expiring per hour or so. Meaning, on client-side, when I'm requesting the server to fetch media posts, using the token, the response returns with expired token exception.

I tried to use [FB Access Token Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) to check the token validity, and it shows that the token does indeed expire in about an hour. Why is this happening? I checked the response I'm getting from the long-lived token API, and it's a success with the **token**, **grant_type**, and **expires_in** fields.

Below is the screenshot of the debugger result.
[image: Screenshot of Debugger Result].

What I'm trying to accomplish is rather straight-forward. Generate a long-lived access token that "should" be valid for 60-days use on server side. Then, I'll have to automate the token-refresh process afterwards. Any suggestions to the above issue?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Moh. Bokhari

Answer (score 1):

The difficult part is getting a short-lived access token first; I found this useful page which explains step-by-step with screenshots on how to get a short-lived access token.

[The link to the website](http://www.mutface.com/solved-how-to-get-instagram-short-lived-access-token-step-by-step-guide-2020/)

Comment: I am using the same method to display posts. My question is what happen when the token expires will it generate the token by itself or do we have to follow create token again for the user we gave permission to. I mean in client side will the posts be available or gone?